# Angular validation message to be hidden on editing input

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following html content in my page. Here upon submit click I perform some server side validation to check for duplicate names. If its a duplicate then I show a message. Now when user edits the input I want the error message to be hidden even before clicking on save button. How do I do it?

```
<form name="vm.createStepForm" ng-submit="vm.saveStepDefinition(vm.createStepForm.$valid)" novalidate>
                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span for="step_definition_name" class="col-md-4 step-builder-label">{{'customWorkflow:stepBuilder.stepName' | i18next }}</span>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="step_definition_name" name="step_definition_name" required ng-disabled="vm.stepDefinition.canDelete == false" ng-model="vm.stepDefinition.name" />
                                        <div ng-show="vm.createStepForm.$submitted">
                                            <div class="validation-error-text" ng-show="createStepForm.step_definition_name.$error.required">
                                                {{'customWorkflow:stepBuilder.stepNameRequiredError' | i18next}}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="validation-error-text" ng-show="vm.duplicateStepName && !createStepForm.step_definition_name.$dirty">
                                                {{'customWorkflow:stepBuilder.duplicateStepName' | i18next}}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <hr />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="button" ng-click="vm.cancel()" id="btn_create_step_cancel">{{ 'customWorkflow:stepBuilder.cancel' | i18next }}</button>
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;" type="submit" id="btn_save_step" ng-disabled="(vm.createStepForm.$invalid || stepResultsForm.$invalid)" value="{{ 'customWorkflow:stepBuilder.save' | i18next }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

[image: First image showing the error]

Now when I change the name and tab out I want the error message not to be shown

[image: Now when I change the name and tab out I want the error message not to be shown]

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) event on your input and set `duplicateStepName` as false

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="step_definition_name" name="step_definition_name" ng-change="change()" required ng-disabled="vm.stepDefinition.canDelete == false" ng-model="vm.stepDefinition.name" />
```

then in controller

```
$scope.change=function(){
  $scope.duplicateStepName=false
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/29wk8dxf/)